# Google nearby connections - sending payload does not work after reconnecting a few times

Tags: google-nearby

I want to create offline multiplayer game for android, so I need reliable p2p communication between devices. Google nearby connections work quite ok, but I found one issue. Setup is standard - device A advertises, device D discovers and connects to A. Then D disconnects, discovers again and connects again. After one to ten iterations D can still connect to A and receive data from A, but it can no longer send data. I call `sendPayload` with `Payload.fromBytes`, I receive `onSuccessCallback`, but A does not receive this payload. Later on D receives `onPayloadTransferUpdate` with status code 2. Further reconnects does not solve the problem. Only thing that solves the problem reliably is reboot.

Some logs:
`03-21 12:20:25.827 30317-30317/com.alienff.ntest I/Log: [21.03.2018 12:20:25.827] [main] MainActivity: sending payload -5864147190526311071
03-21 12:20:25.841 30317-30317/com.alienff.ntest I/Log: [21.03.2018 12:20:25.841] [main] MainActivity: payload cent
...
03-21 12:21:16.925 3066-3215/? D/WifiStateMachine: Current network is: "___mm___" , ID is: 0
03-21 12:21:16.926 3066-3215/? D/WifiStateMachine: Current network is still qualified due to heavy traffic, txSuccessRate=2.1973258256066233 rxSuccessRate=0.0
03-21 12:21:16.926 3066-3215/? D/WifiStateMachine: Current network is 5GHz, bail out...
03-21 12:21:17.408 4049-4049/? D/io_stats: !@ 179,0 r 906136 23065676 w 370340 7270584 d 46705 2438912 f 147311 147270 iot 680350 657112 th 51200 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 55938.769
03-21 12:21:17.571 10176-30596/? W/NearbyConnections: Unexpected call to physicalConnectionClosed() for medium WIFI_LAN while NearbyRecorder has active medium BLUETOOTH -- metadata{ service_id: 0 }
03-21 12:21:17.576 10176-30596/? W/NearbyConnections: Unexpected call to physicalConnectionClosed() for medium WIFI_LAN with no corresponding EstablishedConnection that was previously opened. -- metadata{ service_id: 0 }
03-21 12:21:17.579 10176-30596/? W/NearbyConnections: NearbyRecorder expected no more active physical connections before logging this endpoint connection. -- metadata{ service_id: 0 }
03-21 12:21:17.585 3336-3929/? E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: setRfcommConnected false
03-21 12:21:17.586 30317-30317/com.alienff.ntest I/Log: [21.03.2018 12:21:17.586] [main] MainActivity: onPayloadTransferUpdate. endpointId: 7oRz payloadId: -5864147190526311071 bytesTransferred: 0 status: 2
03-21 12:21:17.597 30317-30317/com.alienff.ntest I/Log: [21.03.2018 12:21:17.596] [main] MainActivity: onDisconnected: 7oRz`

Do you know how to make google nearby connections reconnect reliably?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this before, so I'm going to have you do some debugging for me.

1. Give me the model names of all the devices you can reproduce this on.
2. Tell me what type of Payload (BYTE, FILE, STREAM) you're sending.
3. Reproduce this bug while running logcat. Look for the log tags "NearbyConnections" and "NearbyMediums". Let me know if you see any errors/warnings.
4. Reproduce this bug, and then force kill your app. Wait 45 seconds. You should see Wifi/Bluetooth toggle off/on. Reopen the app and try to reproduce again.

**Current thoughts:**
Status Code 2 is "PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.FAILURE". Usually that's immediately followed by a disconnection because the socket is assumed broken. However, it doesn't look like the socket has gone bad. You're still receiving data and, internally, we send a flurry of control messages over the socket when connecting and those are all going through successfully or you wouldn't get onConnectionResult. That means something is going wrong with the Payload itself; either on your side, or ours. I suspect you're sending either FILE or STREAM payloads because I don't know of a way that BYTE payloads can fail. FILE payloads can fail if the file has moved or the ParcelFileDescriptor becomes invalid. STREAM payloads can fail if the socket/ParceFileDescriptor are closed or garbage collected.

Disclaimer: I work on Nearby Connections

Comment: Let me quickly answer some questions.
1. Samsung A5 2017, Samsung galaxy s3 duos
2. I use BYTE, as I said in my question :)
For others, I will do this tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, darn. It is BYTE? I wonder what could be going wrong... Could you also look up the Google Play Services version number (in Settings > Apps)? And once you're in a bad state, can you keep the devices connected by not send anything for ~30seconds?

Comment: I have added logs to the question. This is what I've got so far.
Apparently, this is not as easy to reproduce as I thought. Still trying to figure out what exactly causes this problem.

Comment: Version of Google Play Services is 12.2.21 (448-188803320).
When I was in a bad state I did not send any data for about 2 minutes, then I sent data from A to D (arrived) and from D to A (did not arrive and also no onPayloadTransferUpdate were called. Usually, when D unable to send data it receives onPayloadTransferUpdate with status 2 and then disconnects.)

Comment: Based off of the logs, it looks like we're getting into a bad state somehow. That's not good... I'll write a test case for this and hopefully I can reproduce it locally.

Comment: For sure something else is needed to reproduce this except just connect-disconnect. By I can not pin-point what exactly...